# A chef recipe to install ruby 1.9.3 system wide without rvm nor rbenv

Tags: ruby, chef-solo, chef, cookbook

I'm looking for an Opscode [Chef cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks) that installs system-wide Ruby version 1.9.3, patch-level latest at the time of the run_list execution.

Have done some research and there is a [Brightbox PPA](http://docs.brightbox.com/ruby/ubuntu/) available at least for Ubuntu flavors.

I wonder if there is a well written cross-platform Chef cookbook that replace old 1.8.7 Ruby by 1.9.3 or better without depending on RVM nor rbenv.

Comment: Could you specify for which operating system and version? I guess that's quite relevant especially since not all cookbookes/repositories work on all operating systems

Comment: Sure! I would say at least Ubuntu/Debian based distros. Preferable any *nix and ideal would include Mac OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this (at least on Ubuntu) by using the `cookbook 'ruby_build', '>= 0.8.0'` with this simple recipe:

```
include_recipe 'ruby_build'

ruby_build_ruby '1.9.3-p484' do
  prefix_path '/usr/local'
  action :install
end
```

Note the prefix_path i used worked perfectly fine on Ubuntu 12.04 since `/usr/local/bin` is already in system $PATH

Quote:

> `/usr/local` is a place to install files built by the administrator usually by using the make command

Comment: Can you link to the cookbook used?

Comment: http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/ruby_build

Comment: https://github.com/elgalu/jenkins-box-for-travis/blob/d93a35/recipes/replace_system_ruby.rb#L11